# Copy task does not put copied files into its TaskOutputs - why?

Tags: java, gradle

With one file `build.gradle` in directory `in` and the following tasks:

```
task cpy(type: Copy) {
  from 'in'
  into 'out'
}

tast testIn << {
  println cpy.inputs.files.files
}

task testOut << {
  println cpy.outputs.files.files
}
```

Why does `gradle testOut` only print:

`[...\out]`

when `gradle testIn` prints:

`[...\in\build.gradle]`

Clearly there's an inconsistency here. The task input specifies the exact files that it has copied, but the output only specifies the directory to which it has copied the files, not the files themselves. Is this on purpose?

I can think of numerous cases where knowing the final paths of the files copied is useful. One would be when undoing a copy operation; without the actual file paths after copy one has to manually construct them by traversing the input files and appending their names to the output path. And what about Gradles "up-to-date" functionality - if `cpy.outputs` is the whole directory, even though it only copied one file, then the snapshot taken by Gradle covers way more than it should.

Answer (score 0):

The outputs of the `Copy` task are currently defined as a single output directory. It's a known limitation.